# use top with list of parameters

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have this spring data repository method

```
public FileActivity findTopByFileIDOrderByCreatedDesc(String fileID);
```

This works fine . But how do I make it work for list of parameters ?

This doesn't work (I can have many FileActivity for file id - but I want only the last one) :

```
public List<FileActivity> findTopByFileIDOrderByCreatedDesc(List<String> fileIDs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data's support for derived queries is useful but for anything other than simple queries it is probably easier and clearer just to define your own JPQL query.

```
@Query("select f from File f where f.id in :fileIds order by f.created desc")
public Page<FileActivity> findTopFilesById(
                             @Param("fileIDs") List<String> fileIDs, Pageable pageable);
```

As JPQL does not have a limit keyword you can simply pass in a Page.

```
List<String> fileIds = //;
Page<File> page = repository.findTopFilesById(fileIds, new PageRequest(0, fileIds.size());
List<File> files = page.getContent();
```

You could also dynamically specify the sort order in the PageRequest rather than in the JPQL giving a bit more flexibility:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public FileActivity findTopByFileIDInOrderByCreatedDesc(Collection<String> fileIDs);
```

See more examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java)

Note - if you use 'Top' then you get only one record. To get more than one record you have to add a number to 'Top' for example: 'Top10'.

More info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Comment: no but I want to get a List<FileActivity> in return , and when I use your suggestion (after changing the return type to List<FileActivity>) I'm getting only one record in the list no matter how many ids I sent as parameters

Comment: ok but this is not a constant . fileIDs parameter will vary of course on run time , and the result list has to be in the same size as the fileIDs size

Comment: @user7916020 do you agree that this is completely another question?